# How to add elements to array of Chart in vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, charts

I'm trying to add 14 scatter charts to a chart sheet in a new workbook.  The following code does not store the new chart in the dynamic array.

```
   Sub GenerateViewSheets()

   Dim curBook As Workbook
   ' Create new worksheet
   Dim NewBook As Workbook
   Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

   'Add a sheet
   Dim chrt As Chart
   Set chrt = NewBook.Charts.Add(Before:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
   chrt.Activate

   'Add charts   
   Dim nCharts As Integer
   Dim iChrt As Integer
   Dim chartArray() As Chart
   nCharts = 14
   ReDim chartArray(1 To nCharts) As Chart

   With chrt
      For i = 1 To nCharts
         Set chartArray(i) = .ChartObjects.Add(1, 1, 20, 20) ' Left, Top, Width, Height
      Next i
   End With
   End Sub
```

The error message is

```
  Error #  13
  Generated by VBAProject
  Error Line: 0
  Error Desc: Type mismatch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change array type to ChartObject:

```
   Sub GenerateViewSheets()

   Dim curBook As Workbook
   Dim NewBook As Workbook

   Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

   'Add a sheet
   Dim chrt As Chart
   Set chrt = NewBook.Charts.Add(Before:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
   chrt.Activate

   'Add charts
   Dim nCharts As Integer
   Dim iChrt As Integer
   Dim chartArray() As ChartObject

   nCharts = 14
   ReDim chartArray(1 To nCharts) As ChartObject

   With chrt
      For i = 1 To nCharts
         Set chartArray(i) = .ChartObjects.Add(1, 1, 20, 20) ' Left, Top, Width, Height
      Next i
   End With

End Sub
```